# regarding shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method

Tags: view

I am working on an application in which some viewControllers used. When I push from one view to another view in Landscape/Portrait mode and move back in same mode the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method called on move back.

but when same steps repeat and on second or third view change the orientation and move back then shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method not called. and view controls got disturbed.

Please give a solid solution for the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to get called on the second or third viewController on the stack of viewControllers when orientation of device changes.

**shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation only gets called on the top viewController**. If you do any layout code in the method of second or third viewController, code is not executed.

Solutions are simple and many, depending on your code. Here's one that should work (not tested in Xcode). In the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method of your top ViewController, add something like:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in [self childViewControllers])
{ 
    [vc shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

If you have a pointer to a specific childViewController, you could call it specifically.

Note from documentation:

> Your implementation of this method should simply return YES or NO based on the value in the interfaceOrientation parameter. Do not attempt to get the value of the interfaceOrientation property or check the orientation value reported by the UIDevice class. Your view controller is either capable of supporting a given orientation or it is not.

To do any layout, you can use:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Hope this helps!